# How can I switch the Bool animated in Swift (in the override ViewWillAppear methode)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-authentication, uikit

I want to present one Storyboard after loading the App if the User is logged in and an other if the user have to log In.

I did it by overwriting the V`iewWillAppear` method, which now contains the code that is routed to the other storyboard when the user is logged in.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        
        let userdefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        if userdefaults.string(forKey: "autoemail") != nil {
            let email = userdefaults.string(forKey: "autoemail")
            let password = userdefaults.string(forKey: "autopass")
            Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email!, password: password!) { (user, error) in
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "SignInSeguettt", sender: nil)
            }
        }
    }override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        
        let userdefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        if userdefaults.string(forKey: "autoemail") != nil {
            let email = userdefaults.string(forKey: "autoemail")
            let password = userdefaults.string(forKey: "autopass")
            Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email!, password: password!) { (user, error) in
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "SignInSeguettt", sender: nil)
            }
        }
    }
```

But now the screen that would otherwise appear for a second still comes. How can I avoid that? I thought maybe by setting animated to false. I don't know how I can do this, because if I do it like that i get this Error:

> Method does not override any method from its superclass

Are there other ways to get around this brief appearance of the wrong controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think loading a view controller then making a decision whether to display it or load another view controller is the best approach to what you are trying to do.

The way I determine whether to allow the user to proceed into the app, or if they are not logged in display the login screen is done in the SceneDelegate.swift class (or could be done in the AppDelegate class if your app doesnt have a SceneDelegate)

It's done like this:

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?

    override init() {
        FirebaseApp.configure() // Configure Firebase
    }
    
    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {

        var vc: UIViewController // Create a viewcontroller ready to return as the viewcontroller we are going to show to the user

        if (Auth.auth().currentUser) != nil { // The users' auth token is still good, they are logged in
            let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil) // get a storyboard reference
            
            // Make our holding view controller an instance of the Main storyboard's initial view controller
            vc = mainStoryboard.instantiateInitialViewController()! 
            
        } else { // the user is not logged in
            // Has the user seen the onboarding screen before?
            if Session.HasShownOnboarding { // Yes has seen the onboardinng screens
                let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Account", bundle: nil) // get reference to the Account storyboard
                
                // Make our holding view controller an instance of the Account storyboard's Log In view controller
                vc = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "LoginViewController")

            } else { // No the user has not been shown the onboarding screens yet
                let launchStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Onboarding", bundle: nil) // get reference to the Onboarding storyboard
                
                // Make our holding view controller an instance of the Onboading storyboard's Onboarding view controller
                vc = launchStoryboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "OnboardingViewController")
                Session.HasShownOnboarding = true
            }
        }

        // Make the app's default view controller to display, whatever we set from the logic above, either Main, or Login, or Onboarding
        self.window?.rootViewController = vc
    }


// ...

}
```

Comment: Hey @latenitecoder Thanks, it works great! I have an other question: How can I switch if a button is pressed the storyboard file? I mean I know how you can switch the storyboards in one file with segues but how can I do this with different files? Thanks Boothosh

Comment: You just follow the steps above for Session.HasShownOnboarding in your @IBAction naming the storyboard. If it's the initial view controller you can use  yourStoryboard.instantiateInitialViewController if it's in the storyboard but not the first view shown use youStoryboard.instantiateViewController identifier yourViewController's name